# Django: DurationField with resolution in microseconds

Tags: django, datetime, django-admin

The django DurationField displays only HH:MM:SS in the django admin interface.

Unfortunately this is not enough in my current context.

I need to be able to show/edit microseconds in the admin interface.

How could this be done?

**Update**

This was a mistake. My data in the database was wrong. The microseconds where removed in a process before the data came into the database.

Django displayes the microseconds if there are any. You don't need to do anything to show them.

Answer (score 2):

Have a look on source:

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/_modules/django/db/models/fields/#DurationField

I think the way is to override `forms.DurationField` (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/_modules/django/forms/fields/#DurationField) and to be exact these method:

`from django.utils.duration import duration_string`

```
def duration_string(duration):
    """Version of str(timedelta) which is not English specific."""
    days, hours, minutes, seconds, microseconds = _get_duration_components(duration)

    string = '{:02d}:{:02d}:{:02d}'.format(hours, minutes, seconds)
    if days:
        string = '{} '.format(days) + string
    if microseconds:
        string += '.{:06d}'.format(microseconds)

    return string
```

be aware that there may be need to override these too `django.utils.dateparse.parse_duration`

```
def parse_duration(value):
    """Parse a duration string and return a datetime.timedelta.

    The preferred format for durations in Django is '%d %H:%M:%S.%f'.

    Also supports ISO 8601 representation and PostgreSQL's day-time interval
    format.
    """
    match = standard_duration_re.match(value)
    if not match:
        match = iso8601_duration_re.match(value) or postgres_interval_re.match(value)
    if match:
        kw = match.groupdict()
        days = datetime.timedelta(float(kw.pop('days', 0) or 0))
        sign = -1 if kw.pop('sign', '+') == '-' else 1
        if kw.get('microseconds'):
            kw['microseconds'] = kw['microseconds'].ljust(6, '0')
        if kw.get('seconds') and kw.get('microseconds') and kw['seconds'].startswith('-'):
            kw['microseconds'] = '-' + kw['microseconds']
        kw = {k: float(v) for k, v in kw.items() if v is not None}
        return days + sign * datetime.timedelta(**kw)
```